# How do I use ajax to update HERE maps api with a new search results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, here-api

I am migrating from google maps API to HERE maps api and using ajax to update a list of parking stalls and having that list plotted on the HERE map. I am using the Ransack search rails gem and geocoder and rails 5. I have it operating successfully on an initial location search.
however when the user updates the search the list is generated successfully however the map is not being updated with the new results. Expected results user enters a new requirement in submit form presses enter
the list is generated using ajax and then the map is also refreshed with ajax with the new results as well.

for this initialize statement the portion below is what I used for google map that was successful when executed with google

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
initialize(<%= raw @arrParkings.to_json %>)
});
```

This is what I have currently with HERE map in the first script initialize(<%= raw @arrParkings.to_json %>)

what would be the equivalent command for HERE maps to have ajax refresh the map successfully with the list results?

I have review these docs and may be on the right track how to implement it with ajax?
https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-mapevents-event.html

my loaded API scripts below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css?dp- 
version=1533195059"/>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
```

My searchmap.html.erb partail view

```
    <script>


        var mapLocation = {lat: <%= @arrParkings[0].latitude %>, lng: <%= 
    @arrParkings[0].longitude %> };
        var zoomLvl = 15;

        var M = {
            'Init' : { // sign up http://developer.here.com for app_id and 
    app_code
            'app_id':   'app_id',
            'app_code': 'app-code',
            useHTTPS: true
        },
        'Behavior' :    {},         // Manage map behaviors
        'Container' :   {},         // Reference to DOM object containing map
        'Lat' :         mapLocation.lat,   // Latitude
        'Layers' :      {},         // Map layers
        'Lng' :         mapLocation.lng,       // Longitude
        'Map' :         {},         // Map object
        'Platform' :    {},         // Core to HERE API
        'UI' :          {},         // User interface and interaction
        'Zoom' :        zoomLvl           // 1 == global, 15 == street level
    };
    // Obtain reference to mapContainer in DOM
    M.Container = document.getElementById('mapContainer');
    // Store initialized platform object
    M.Platform = new H.service.Platform(M.Init);
    // Store reference to layers object
    M.Layers = M.Platform.createDefaultLayers(); //default setup!!
    // Create map object initialized with container and style
    // Set map style - example M.Layers.satellite.map
    M.Map = new H.Map(M.Container, M.Layers.normal.map);
    // Create behavior object initialized with map object
    M.Behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(M.Map));
    // Store UI object associated with map object and layers object
    M.UI = H.ui.UI.createDefault(M.Map, M.Layers);



        // Instantiate (and display) a map object:
        function displayMap() {
            M.Map.setCenter({lat:M.Lat, lng:M.Lng});
            M.Map.setZoom(M.Zoom);
        }

        function addMarkerToGroup(group, coordinate, html) {
        var marker = new H.map.Marker(coordinate);
        // add custom data to the marker
        marker.setData(html);
        group.addObject(marker);
    }

    function addInfoBubble(map, parkings) {
        var group = new H.map.Group();

        map.addObject(group);

        // add 'tap' event listener, that opens info bubble, to the group
        group.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
            // event target is the marker itself, group is a parent event target
            // for all objects that it contains
            var bubble =  new H.ui.InfoBubble(evt.target.getPosition(), {
                // read custom data
                content: evt.target.getData()
            });
            // show info bubble
            M.UI.addBubble(bubble);
        }, false);

        parkings.forEach(function(parking) {
            addMarkerToGroup(group, { lat: parking.latitude, lng: parking.longitude },
                "<div><a href='parkings/" + parking.id + "'><div class='map_price'>$" + parking.daily_price + "/Day</div>" + parking.listing_name+ "");
        });

    }


    // Create the default UI components

    // Default marker reference: https://developer.here.com/blog/how-to-migrate-from-google-map-markers-to-here-map-markers

    function displayDefaultMarker() {
        //marker for location
        let locationMarker = new H.map.Marker(mapLocation);
        M.Map.addObject(locationMarker);
    }

    function initialize(parkings) {
        parkings.forEach(function(parking) {
            // console.log("location: " + location);
            let marker = new H.map.Marker({lat: parking.latitude, lng: parking.longitude});
            M.Map.addObject(marker);
        });


        displayMap();
        displayDefaultMarker();
        addInfoBubble(M.Map, parkings);
    }



    initialize(<%= raw @arrParkings.to_json %>)


    // for the initaize statment above this portion below is what I used for google map that was sucesssful when I executed with google
    //
    //     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
    //         initialize(<%= raw @arrParkings.to_json %>)
    //     });




</script>
```

my parking list partial

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading preview">
            <%= image_tag parking.cover_photo(:medium) %>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <%= link_to parking.listing_name, parking %><br/>
            $<%= parking.daily_price %> | <%= parking.attractions %> | <%= parking.accommodate %>
            <div id="star_<%= parking.id %>"></div> <%= pluralize(parking.average_rating, "review") %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

a view of my form to submit enhanced search that is updating the list through ajax but the HERE map is not being updated with the same results. Utilizing Ransack gem

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label> Search for nearby buildings, services or attractions by 
    name</label>
            <%= f.search_field :attractions_cont_any, placeholder: "EG Arena's Name", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row text-center">
    <%= f.submit "Search", class: "btn btn-form" %>
</div>
```

my js folder search.js.erb that is updating the list results successfully and that I used when using Google

```
$('#parking_listing').html('<%= j render partial: 
"parkings/parkings_list", locals: {parkings: @arrParkings} %>')
initialize(<%= raw @arrParkings.to_json %>)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end you need to trigger a new request for the new set of parking places and then refresh the map display for it. Maybe this extended examples helps a bit:

https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/geocoder_autocomplete